# Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is also getting deprecated like Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I have an ASP.NET application built on top of .NET 7.

A couple of months ago, Microsoft deprecated `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`, and the .NET community suggested that replacing it with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` could resolve this issue.
Today, I noticed that the NuGet Package Manager indicates that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` is also deprecated and vulnerable: [Deprecated Microsoft.AspNetCore.App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQcTO.png)

What else could be used instead of these two packages?

I tried to install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` package, but it was declined because it is not supported by the project itself.

Comment: I believe those 2.2 packages are special case because they may have used some dependencies of .net framework 4.x.  In .net-core 2.x you could reference the old .net framework 4.x libraries. (which could also open up vulnerabilities)  core3.x and forward everything was included (or should be) in the new .net and you could no longer reference .net framework 4.x libraries.  Keep it all .NET 7 and you should be good.  MVC should already be included in .NET 7 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say why you were referencing those packages, so I have to guess what your intent is.

If you're trying to update an existing web app, then I suggest creating an empty directory, running `dotnet new mvc` (or have a look at `dotnet new list`, and see if there are any other templates that are more closely aligned with what you want), then compare your existing csproj and the new project's csproj, and copy the bits that seem relevant. Or in your case, see what PackageReferences it has by default, and delete other packages from your csproj, unless your app uses it.

However, I think it's more likely you're trying to create a class library that can reference ASP.NET Core APIs. There's a docs page specifically for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0

It says to add a `FrameworkReference` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. Here's the cspoj sample they have:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Hopefully it's obvious you should use a newer target framework than netcoreapp3.1. The point of the sample is to show the `FrameworkReference`, and it's an MSBuild item, not a property.